# Cut and Table function in R

Tags: r

```
x<-sample(30:60,50,TRUE)
y<-cut(x,breaks=c(30,40,50,60))
y
[1] (30,40] (30,40] (50,60] (40,50] (40,50] (40,50] (40,50] (30,40] (30,40]
[10] (50,60] (30,40] (50,60] (30,40] (30,40] (50,60] (50,60] (50,60] (30,40]
[19] (50,60] (30,40] (40,50] (40,50] (30,40] (30,40] (30,40] (40,50] (30,40]
[28] (50,60] (40,50] (40,50] (30,40] (50,60] (40,50] (50,60] (50,60] (30,40]
[37] (50,60] (50,60] (30,40] (50,60] (30,40] (30,40] <NA> (40,50] (30,40]
[46] (40,50] (30,40] (30,40] (30,40] (30,40]
Levels: (30,40] (40,50] (50,60]
table(y)
y
(30,40] (40,50] (50,60]
23 12 14
table(y)[1]
(30,40]
23
```

Question1:

If right=FALSE is added ,the intervals are
(30,40] (40,50] (50,60]

If right=TRUE is added,the intervals are
[30,40) [40,50) [50,60)

how can i get the interval such as  `[30,40] (40,50] (50,60]` or '[30,40) [40,50) [50,60]`?

Question2:

```
table(y)[1]  
(30,40]
23
```

I know there are 23 numbers in the interval (30,40], I can get them all with
`x[x<=40 & x>30]`.
Is there any better way to get the result?

Comment: set the `include.lowest` parameter to `TRUE`?

Comment: question 1 is solved,how about question 2?

Comment: the parameter only includes `[30,40]` (the lowest). It'll still be `(40, 50]` and `(50, 60]`. I am not sure if this is what you desire. Can you tell what exactly you want? You want to be able to subset all values from 30 to 40, and 40 - 50, etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question # 2 it depends on what you mean by "better".

Here is one option:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
x[ 30 %<% x %<=% 40 ]
```

Or, instead of using `cut` you can use `findInterval`:

```
y <- findInterval(x, c(30,40,50,60))
x[ y==1 ]
```

You could also look at the `subset` function.

If these don't match your definition of "better", then tell us more about what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, simply use the output of your cut

```
x[y == "(30,40]"]
```