# Two-way frequency distribution table for a quantitive data in R

Tags: r, frequency-distribution, two-way

I'm having difficult time to crate a two-way frequency distribution table for a tree diameter-height data. I have a dataset like below

```
dbh(cm) tht(m)
3   53.35
19  13.37
27  16.53
22  17.8
9   8.33
10  8.76
24  15.62
44  30.3
17  14.91
10  8.93
```

I need to create a frequency distribution table for this data with classes for both columns. My class bounds are like,

for diameter:

```
8 - 11.9
12 - 15.9
16 - 19.9 and so.
```

for height:

```
3 - 4.9
5 - 6.9
7 - 8.9 and so.
```

So I have thousands of rows of data and summing up each frequency in itself is a total pain. I wrote the following lines (dbh represents diameter and tht is height);

```
> data <- read.csv('data.csv')
> diameter <- data$dbh
> range(diameter)
[1]  6.0 60.5
> breaks <- seq(6, 61, by=4)
> diameter.cut <- cut(diameter, breaks, right = FALSE)
> diameter.frq <- table(diameter.cut)
> cbind(diameter.frq)
        diameter.frq
[6,10)            35
[10,14)           77
[14,18)           59
[18,22)           25
[22,26)           25
[26,30)           51
[30,34)           38
[34,38)           28
[38,42)           21
[42,46)           22
[46,50)           14
[50,54)            2
[54,58)            6
>
```

I can do the same thing to the tree height (tht). But the problem is how do I create a 'cross frequence table'

For example: there are 35 trees in `[6,10)` diameter class. But I need to distribute these 35 trees into each height class. Let's say 12 of these trees belong to `[3,5)` height class, 8 of them in `[5,7)`...etc.

*P.S: I'm pretty new in R. So my problem might seem pretty dummy but I really digged the internet before I post here. I'm sorry for that.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cut and Table function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848289/cut-and-table-function-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this? After tweaking your code I got...

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(diameter.cm = cut(diameter.cm, seq(range(diameter.cm)[1], range(diameter.cm)[2]+4, by=4), right = F),
         height.m = cut(height.m, seq(range(height.m)[1], range(height.m)[2]+2, by=2), right = F)) %>%
  group_by(diameter.cm, height.m) %>%
  tally()
```

**Output is:**

```
  diameter.cm height.m        n
1 [3,7)       [52.3,54.3)     1
2 [7,11)      [8.33,10.3)     3
3 [15,19)     [14.3,16.3)     1
4 [19,23)     [12.3,14.3)     1
5 [19,23)     [16.3,18.3)     1
6 [23,27)     [14.3,16.3)     1
7 [27,31)     [16.3,18.3)     1
8 [43,47)     [28.3,30.3)     1
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(diameter.cm = c(3L, 19L, 27L, 22L, 9L, 10L, 24L, 
44L, 17L, 10L), height.m = c(53.35, 13.37, 16.53, 17.8, 8.33, 
8.76, 15.62, 30.3, 14.91, 8.93)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: This is the exact thing that I was looking for. It works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped!